# Como generar imagenes binarias de una captura de la camara del telefono sin que las sombras afecten

Tags: android, android-studio, imagen

Intento crear una aplicacion que sea capaz de tomar una foto y aplicar un filtro a la imagen tomada de tal forma que se genere una imagen binaria.
Mi problema radica en las sombras, las sombras se vuelven de color negro y la mayoria de la imagen se arruina. 
Este es el codigo que se encarga de aplicar el definir el filtro para la imagen.

```
private static ColorMatrix getColorMatrix(){
    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);

    float m = 255f;
    float t = -255*128f;
    ColorMatrix threshold = new ColorMatrix(new float[]{
            m, 0, 0, 1, t,
            0, m, 0, 1, t,
            0, 0, m, 1, t,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0
    });
    colorMatrix.postConcat(threshold);
    return colorMatrix;
}
```

Y el  de acá lo aplica

```
private static Bitmap aplicarFiltro(Bitmap bmp){
    int width = bmp.getWidth();
    int height = bmp.getHeight();

    Bitmap img = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas colox = new Canvas(img);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(binarizeMatrix()));
    colox.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);

    return img;
}
```

Comment: si quieres que la imagen sea solo binaria (blanco o negro), entonces esperas que las sombras sean blancas? por que a mi punto de vista, esta bien que sean negras

Comment: @YorchSircam lo se, pero estaba pensando mas bien en algun filtro que pueda deshacerse de ellas.